# rickshaw: how to translate days months?

Tags: d3.js, rickshaw

Im trying to get the tooltip info for rickshaw graphs with numbers and dates formated as continental Europe, months in spanish and days also in spanish.

Any leads on how to get the month names and day names translated to spanish, also how to implement it?

Thanks

UPDATE Got this files. Rickshaw.Fixtures.Time.js and Rickshaw.Fixtures.Time.Local.js where translated just to see if works but no results or i dont know how to implement those.

```
12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.            17.514 d3.layout.min.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.            57.228 d3.min.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.           239.674 d3.v2.js
    28/04/2014  12:40 p.m.           144.719 d3.v3.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             2.881 extensions.js
    01/05/2014  02:35 a.m.                 0 files.txt
    17/11/2013  04:48 p.m.            90.656 raphael-min.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             6.446 Rickshaw.Class.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             1.437 Rickshaw.Color.Palette.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             3.523 Rickshaw.Compat.ClassList.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             2.178 Rickshaw.Fixtures.Color.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             1.105 Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.               916 Rickshaw.Fixtures.RandomData.js
    30/04/2014  12:34 a.m.             2.683 Rickshaw.Fixtures.Time.js
    30/04/2014  12:38 a.m.             2.683 Rickshaw.Fixtures.Time.Local.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             1.486 Rickshaw.Graph.Ajax.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             3.018 Rickshaw.Graph.Annotate.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             1.907 Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             3.047 Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             2.909 Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.               824 Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y.Scaled.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             1.920 Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Highlight.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             1.058 Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Order.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             3.757 Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             5.369 Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             6.760 Rickshaw.Graph.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.               279 Rickshaw.Graph.JSONP.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             1.383 Rickshaw.Graph.Legend.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             1.534 Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             2.189 Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.Area.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             2.838 Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.Bar.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             3.714 Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.               633 Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.Line.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             2.070 Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.LinePlot.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             2.871 Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.Multi.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             1.174 Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.ScatterPlot.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.               692 Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.Stack.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             1.364 Rickshaw.Graph.Smoother.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.               417 Rickshaw.Graph.Unstacker.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.               756 Rickshaw.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.            61.096 rickshaw.min.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             2.147 Rickshaw.Series.FixedDuration.js
    12/08/2013  03:39 a.m.             3.291 Rickshaw.Series.js
```

And this code for the graph load.

```
function grafica(){


    graph =  new Rickshaw.Graph.Ajax( {
            element: document.getElementById("rickshaw"),

            height: 200,
            renderer: 'line',
            dataURL: 'data.json',
            onData: function(d) { d[0].data[0].y = 80; return d },
     onComplete: function(transport) {
                var graph = transport.graph;
                var detail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({ graph: graph });
                var xAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time({graph: graph });
                xAxis.render();
                var yAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y( {
                graph: graph,
                tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
                ticksTreatment: ticksTreatment
                });
                var legend = new Rickshaw.Graph.Legend( {
                graph: graph,
                element: document.getElementById('legend')
                }); 

                yAxis.render();
                var shelving = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle( {
                graph: graph,
                legend: legend
                } );

                var order = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Order( {
                graph: graph,
                legend: legend
                } );

                var highlighter = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Highlight( {
                graph: graph,
                legend: legend
                } );    
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Positiva',
                    color: '#0aa699'
                }, {
                    name: 'Negativa',
                    color: '#f35958'
                }, {
                    name: 'Todos',
                    color: '#6060c0'
                }
            ]
        } );
    var ticksTreatment = 'glow';
    }
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Thats what ive have so far, except for the data series content which i guess is not relevant. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not quite a JS pro I won't help you translating the Stuff. But I know where you have to use it:

```
graph =  new Rickshaw.Graph.Ajax( {
        ....
 onComplete: function(transport) {
            var graph = transport.graph;
            var detail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({ graph: graph });
            ...
        },
...        } );
var ticksTreatment = 'glow';
}
```

The magic part you are looking for is:

```
                var detail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({ graph: graph });
```

You can add there a xFormatter and yFormatter

```
var hoverDetail2 = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({graph: graph,
    xFormatter: function(x) {ConvertHowever you Like},
    yFormatter: function(y) {ConvertHowever you Like}
});
```

Make sure to return a value in your x- and yFormatter. The value you Return will be Displayed as tooltip when hovering.

Hope this Helps

Comment: Thanks Loki. i cant fill in with any update for this since ive switched to highcharts lib.